# How to make my shopping cart and favorites button responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a shopping cart and favorites button in my boostrap nav-bar. When I hit 992 px the navbar switches to a hamburger collapse menu which is fine for the dropdown in my navbar but it makes my cart and favorites button spread out. I need help displaying  these buttons from the dropdown in a way that makes sense for the user on tablet and mobile devices. below is my code for the nav as well as a link to the site.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" ></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" aria-current="page" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Category
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mens</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Jackets</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Outer Wear</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-current="page" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Collection
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Winter</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Spring</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Summer</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fall</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
          <span class="navbar">
            
            <i> <a type="button" class="btn fab fa-gratipay"href="favorites.html" target="_self"> <span class="favoritesCount"></span> </a></i>
               
            <i> <a type="button" class="btn fas fa-shopping-cart Cart" href="cart.html" target="_self"  ><span class="navbarCart" data-totalitems="0"></span></a></i>
          
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </section>
```

here is the CSS

```
/* nav container */
.container-fluid{
  border-bottom: black solid 3px ;
  width: 100%;
  
  height: 50px;
  
}
.container-fluid a{
  margin-left: 3%;
  
}
/* .navbar-brand
{
    position: relative;
    background: url(../images/logo.png);
    width: 170px;
    left: 15px;
    max-height: 70px; 
} */
.navbar-brand
{
    position: relative;
    background: url(../images/fakeLogo.png);
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}


.navbar span{
  padding: 0 8px;
  margin-right: 3%;
}
.Cart{
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

https://connorlewis128.github.io/ShoppingPage/Dist/product.html

please let me know if any more code or information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly...
Do you want your favourites and cart icons to **not** spread across the page?

You need to remove `justify-content: space-between;` from `span.navbar`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the simple fix had to use SCSS which im not that experienced with to remove thanks again!